# CSS Bootstrap navbar- center search bar that takes the whole width on collapse

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a bootstrap v.3 navbar with 3 elements in it. I would like to align elements evenly so that the search bar is centred in the navbar. And when it collapses that it takes the full widht. But struggling to do that.

This is the html for it:

```
      <nav class="navbar navbar-transparent navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">

        <div class="container">
          <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
          <div class="col-lg-4 navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="logo">
          </div>

          <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left navbar-search-form active" role="search">
               <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
               </div>
            </form>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active">
                  <a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><button href="#gsdk" class="btn btn-round btn-default">Sign in</button></li>
            </ul>

          </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
      </nav>
```

I tried to make a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sLeb4v1y/) for it, but it didn't turn out good, but hopefully the code there can give some idea.

Comment: can you add your css too

Comment: the whole css is in the fiddle

Comment: but the fiddle has the whole bootstrap. I am talking about your custom css

Comment: I don't have any custom css

Comment: Have you tried adding the class "text-center"? It should align the child elements to center.

Comment: Ah.. I get it now. So you want the search bar by itself to stay in the  center.

Comment: I see you have col-lg-4 on header block. Can you assign the other elements too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the same without flex and CSS3 properties with some simple tweaks.

Check Demo **[HERE](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/XpNaJe?editors=1100)**

Try this

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-transparent navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">

  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

      <img class="logo" src="//placehold.it/50x50" alt="logo">
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-search-form active" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
      </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><button href="#gsdk" class="btn btn-round btn-default">Sign in</button></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.navbar {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #333;
}

.navbar-nav > li {
  line-height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.logo, .navbar-nav > li > .btn {
  margin: 0 15px;
}

@media (min-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-search-form {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to use `flex` but it has poor browser compatibility, so  you can use `media queries` and `position:absolute;` for `.navbar-form`.

Give `position-relative` to the div `.container` just inside the `nav`. I gave it some border, so you can see the centering. Your `sign in` button is sticking to upper-right corner because you have given it `navbar-right` class.

```css
.navbar-header img{
  width:70px;
  margin:0;
}
.navbar-container{
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid red;
}
.navbar-header button span{
  color:black;
  background-color:green;
}
@media screen and (min-width:768px){
  form.navbar-form{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    margin:0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-transparent navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container navbar-container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <img src="http://www.chinabuddhismencyclopedia.com/en/images/thumb/b/b8/Nature.jpg/240px-Nature.jpg" alt="logo">
    </div>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-search-form active" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
          <a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
        </div>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
         <li><button href="#gsdk" class="btn btn-round btn-default">Sign in</button></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: This method works but it needs another div. See below:    <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">. Can't jump to the next line with the enter key; it invokes the save button. Bad programming.

Answer (score 0):

The class "text-center" in bootstrap 3 is made to align child element to center.

Comment: I tried this in your fiddle and it works. Though resizing makes 2 elements disappear and appear (effects of media query) but they do stay in the center.