# Can't get search box to center in bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have static bootstrap navbar and am trying to center a search box in it. Everything I've tried is not working. Either get it below the navbar or not at all. I now have it showing, but it is displaying above the navbar title on the left, and not at the same vertical position as the rest of the navbar items. I've tried using just form, navbar-center and now a div. None of them work. There must be some simple bootstrap class or css I'm missing.

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default ">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="static/img/CAP-Seal-75x75.png" width=50 height=50 ></a>
            <p style="padding-top:25px;width:120%;"></span>CAWG (TRACS) </p>
        </div>
        <div id="search" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
        <form class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center" role="search">
            <input type="text" class="search form-control input-sm" placeholder="Search" id="sitesearch">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                </form>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="padding-right:20px;">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:1.5em;"></span><i class="icon-angle-down"> </i></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#track_modal_realtime"  data-toggle="modal">Real Time Tracking</a></li>
                        <li><a id="stop_tracking" href="#">Stop Tracking</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#track_modal_historical"  data-toggle="modal">Historical Tracking</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#send_message_modal"  data-toggle="modal">Communications</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#menu-toggle" id="menu-toggle"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-resize-full" aria-hidden="true" id="sizeIcon" style="font-size:1.5em;"></span></a></li><!---->
                <li><a href="#settings_modal" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" style="font-size:1.5em;" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </nav>
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Bootstrap navbar- center search bar that takes the whole width on collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41647632/css-bootstrap-navbar-center-search-bar-that-takes-the-whole-width-on-collapse)

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I have read your question right. If so, you could always do something like this:

```
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default ">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar">                   </span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="static/img/CAP-Seal-75x75.png" width=50 height=50 ></a>
        <p style="padding-top:25px;width:120%;"></span>CAWG (TRACS) </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div id="search" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
      <form class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center" role="search">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="search form-control input-sm" placeholder="Search" id="sitesearch">
          <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></span>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="padding-right:20px;">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:1.5em;"></span><i class="icon-angle-down"> </i></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#track_modal_realtime"  data-toggle="modal">Real Time Tracking</a></li>
              <li><a id="stop_tracking" href="#">Stop Tracking</a></li>
              <li><a href="#track_modal_historical"  data-toggle="modal">Historical Tracking</a></li>
              <li><a href="#send_message_modal"  data-toggle="modal">Communications</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#menu-toggle" id="menu-toggle"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-resize-full" aria-hidden="true" id="sizeIcon" style="font-size:1.5em;"></span></a></li><!---->
          <li><a href="#settings_modal" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" style="font-size:1.5em;" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

By using bootstraps build in cols you can easily center elements by simply splitting your nav into 3 parts.

Hopefully this is what you are after :)

Working example here - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZyMZrY

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thanks, solved my problem!

Comment: Not a problem! Happy coding :)